# Can't create EC2 resource for cloud9 when using a shared AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I tried to create a Cloud9 environment using AWS Cli:

```
aws cloud9 create-environment-ec2 --name my-demo-env --description "My demonstration development environment." --instance-type t2.micro --image-id ami-0123456789876 --subnet-id subnet-0121234eeeee --automatic-stop-time-minutes 180 --connection-type CONNECT_SSM
```

The ami id is a shared resource in the company that we are required to use.

But I receive this message:

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the CreateEnvironmentEC2 operation: Value for ImageId parameter doesn't specify a valid Amazon Machine Image (AMI) supported by AWS Cloud9: ami-0123456789876
```

I tried to put the ami id as "ami-0123456789876", but it didn't work. I verified many times that the id is ok. Please, perhaps do I have to specify something to make it work?

Comment: Is that a custom AMI you built?

Comment: No, it's a custom AMI created by other person and it's shared. For example, if I want to create an EC2 instance in the console, I can select from Recents | My AMIs | Quick Start. I select My AMIs and then "shared with me". Then I can see a list of AMIs and their IDs. That ID I select but it won't work in AWS CLI

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create an "SSH" environment rather than an "EC2" environment if you want to use a custom AMI which doesn't appear to be supported by the CLI.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/create-environment-ssh.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/ec2-env-versus-ssh-env.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/advanced-topics.html